# How to properly set a thread for this case?

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I wrote a code for simultaneous bubble-sorting of an array within two threads, with the use of events (important for assignment) and within a WinForm. Unfortunately, i get the following error in two places at Ascending and Descending action text change:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'`

Here is the code:

```
using System.Threading;

namespace _14
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void ArrayHandler(int[] array);
        public ArrayHandler Ascending;
        public ArrayHandler Descending;
        public string arrayText;
        public int[] array1; public int[] array2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public void Ascending_Action(int[] array)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            textBox2.Text=string.Join(" ", array.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
        }
        public void Function1()
        {
            Ascending += Ascending_Action;
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < array1.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (array1[i]>array1[j])
                    {
                        temp = array1[i];
                        array1[i] = array1[j];
                        array1[j] = temp;
                    }
                    Ascending(array1);
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }
        }


        public void Descending_Action(int[] array)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            textBox3.Text = string.Join(" ", array.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
        }
        public void Function2()
        {
            Descending += Descending_Action;
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < array2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (array2[i] < array2[j])
                    {
                        temp = array2[i];
                        array2[i] = array2[j];
                        array2[j] = temp;
                    }
                    Descending(array2);
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arrayText = textBox1.Text;
            array1 = arrayText.Split(" ").Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray(); array2 = array1;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            button1.Visible = false;
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(Function1);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(Function2);
            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I also made check for which thread accesses the failure point and it returns both of custom-made threads. I don't know which thread is the origin one though, maybe someone can clarify after looking?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(300);` what on earth is that for?

Comment: @Charlieface to "animate" the process of sorting

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the textbox in a method invoker wrap like this:

```
textBox3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                textBox3.Text = string.Join(" ", array2.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
            });
```